# How to add Voice message in jsqmessagesviewcontroller.?

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

how to allow jsqmessages to send audio & Voice messages ??

Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: Anyone can suggest a good way for this ..?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Objective c ...

Comment: I would point you to the example project they have an example there as for getting the audio data that is up to you and your backend. Would only be able to help if you had some code that you had specific question about.

Comment: If you find a solution please can you post it because it can help other. Thank you